# Angular - I couldn't show data on my page

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As i'm new to angular, I couldn't able to show data on my component.html page. I get the Observable but not able to show it on page. it shows ***ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Prabu'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.*** error on the console. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Angular:**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';    
export class AppComponent {
    author$;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.author$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
        this.author$.subscribe(console.log);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="list-group mt-3">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let author of author$ | async">{{author}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Database:**

[image]

**Response on Console:**

[image]

Comment: Please add a sample of how your response looks like.

Comment: @nash11 - I have updated my question. It returns an Observable. As i'm new to this, i have no idea that how to fix.

Comment: That's not helpful. We need to know what the Observable contains. Replace `console.log(this.author$);` with `this.author$.subscribe(console.log);` and show what's in the console.

Comment: @nash11 - I have updated my question.

Comment: Why is your data returning an empty object as the first element? You need to correct that first. Although this can be done in the frontend, it would much be preferred to solve it from your backend first.

Comment: @nash11 - Can you please tell me how can i fix this(Why is your data returning an empty object as the first element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are receiving an object and trying to iterate over it. If you want to iterate over the key-value pairs in an object, you will need to first convert it into an array. You can do this using the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

```html
<ul class="list-group mt-3">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let author of author$ | async | keyvalue">{{author.key}} - {{author.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to simply display the `name` in the template, you can do so like below

```html
<div>
    <!-- To display another item in the object, simply replace name with the required key, eg. (author$ | async)?.students -->
    {{(author$ | async)?.name}}
</div>
```

Your component will now look like this

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class AppComponent {
    author$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.author$ = this.db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
    }
}
```

I have moved the logic to the `ngOnInit` function as that is the best practice rather than doing it in the `contructor` (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#call-it-in-ngoninit)).

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reading-list-frm-database-external-data).

> Note: The `KeyValuePipe` will only work with Angular version 6+

Comment: I use 6.2.3. It is not working. Is it from database complex object or something? I'm not sure.

Comment: Please provide a sample of how your response looks

Comment: I have updated my question. It returns an Observable.

Comment: I have added a way to remove the empty values using Angular.

Comment: The updated answer also not working. Here you can unserstand my issue further better i think. https://stackblitz.com/edit/reading-list-frm-database?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor works on array not object. You are getting a single object of Prabu.In constructor use below line to get all authors.

```
db.object('/authors').valueChanges().subscribe((authors)=>{
 this.author$ = authors.
);
```

In template

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let author of author$ | async">{{author.name}}</li>
```

Comment: It is not working. it Shows " [object Object] " on page.

Comment: In template it should be {{author.name}} . Check updated answer.

Comment: I followed the same. Now it shows " ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined " Error on console.

Comment: Whats the output of console.log(this.author$) in constructor.

Comment: It returns an Observable in the constructor.

Comment: Subscribe to Observable to get value of authors. Check answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198697/discussion-between-pkprabu-and-ranjeet8082).